# Import OpenCV on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, pip, jupyter-notebook

I tried installing OpenCV on Windows 10 using pip.
I used this command-
pip install opencv-contrib-python

After that when I tried importing cv2 on command prompt, it was successfully imported-
[image: Importing cv2 successfully through command prompt]

When I tried importing it on jupyter notebook, this error popped up-
[image: Error when importing cv2 on jupyter notebook]

This is the python version I'm using-
[image: Python version that I am using]

This is pip list and as I've highlighted, opencv-contrib-python version 3.4.3.18 is installed-
[image: pip list]

Then why can't I import OpenCV on jupyter notebook, like tensorflow or numpy are also in pip list and I'm able to import them both through command prompt and also on jupyter notebook.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show the output of `import sys; print(sys.prefix)` for both the cmdline python and your notebook python.

Comment: Are you sure you installed opencv in the same virtual environment you are using with Jupyer?

Comment: Hello Deets, thanks for replying.
On cmdline, output is- C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
On jupyter notebook, output is- C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3

Comment: Hello Ed. Thanks for replying. Earlier when I installed tensorflow, I used-
pip install tensorflow and after that I could import tensorflow both on command prompt and on Jupyter notebook. Then why for OpenCV, I'm facing this problem?

Comment: Usually this error pops up when you launch you jupyter notebook from a different conda environment and your command line is in different conda environment.

for ex -
if you installed opencv in a conda environement called `myenv`,

Ensure that you do 
`(home) C:// conda activate myenv`
and then use
`(myenv) C:// jupyter notebook .` 

(notice that environment is `myenv`)

In your case it seems from the screenshot that you installed cv2 in base, did you also start jupyter notebook from base ?

Answer (score 4):

You have installed openCV in Python running on your Terminal, not into the working environment which Jupyter Notebooks is running from.

Whilst in Terminal write:

```
py -m pip install opencv-python
```

When you use `pip list`

You should see `opencv-python     3.4.3.18`

More information [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).

Comment: Hello Michael. Thank for replying. I was wondering that where exactly did I install OpenCV then. What does pip list show? I mean, I am able to import cv2 on command prompt, but not on python shell and neither on jupyter notebook. So is it like command prompt, anaconda jupyter notebook and python shell independent of each other?

Comment: It would have been installed into your Python Shell. So you could work with opencv2 within the Python PATH. Jupyter needs you to install it into your Windows CMD, to access that module. Though I must confess I am sure someone else more technically minded is better able to answer that question. Also I'm fairly sure the library you installed is not OpenCV but a module for contributing to open CV. See here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Answer (score 2):

In the Anaconda Navigator. Launch conda console as below.
[image]

In the console: run `conda install opencv`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this in anaconda prompt:

First create a new enviorment :

```
conda create -n opencv
```

then :

```
conda activate opencv
```

then:

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

source:youtube

Answer (score 1):

You should open the anaconda prompt and then type:

```
conda install opencv
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you run jupyter not from conda environment, that has opencv module installed.
try to do this:
 `conda activate <your environment>`

```
conda install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

after that try to "import cv2"

Answer (score -1):

0- Sign into your Anaconda

1- Run Anaconda Navigator on your machine. (Which is already installed)

2- Update your Anaconda to the latest version

3-1 Go to the Environments in the right-side panel Conda navigator.

3-1-2 in the search box look for open-cv.

3-1-3 select OpenCV you are interested in the right list will be appeared and check it and then apply.

---

3-2-1 Run Anaconda Prompt from your machine.

3-2-2 By using dos command change the path to the place where your Conda is installed. (For ex, cd c:\ProgramDmdata\Anaconda3)

3-2-3 Run the command: " conda install -c main opencv "

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).