# Can't import cv2 on Jupyter notebook(Anaconda)

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, opencv

I'm using Windows 10.
I have installed OpenCV and it is visible in my pip list-
[I've highlighted the OpenCV package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BrS.png)

When I tried importing cv2 on command prompt and on jupyter notebook-
[cv2 was successfully imported on command prompt, but throws an error on jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlkrN.png)
[Jupyter notebook python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTbzj.png)
[Python version on command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIqnJ.png)
[My jupyter notebook path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE1nR.png)
[sys.prefix gives different outputs on command prompt and juypter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY5kT.png)

Please help me. I don't understand how can I import cv2 on jupyter notebook. I provided all these pictures for details. I'm a newbie, don't know much about environments, paths and all. When I had earlier installed tensorflow through pip using the commans- pip install tensorflow, after that I could successfully import tensorflow both on command prmpt as well as on jupyter notebook. I don't understand why in case of OpenCV, importing on jupyter notebook isn't possible. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the python you are using is installed in your anaconda environment. If that is the case, it will be better to open your Anaconda prompt, activate your environment and install opencv there.

Comment: Hello Osuman. Thanks for replying. Will you please guide me with the steps?

Comment: I used this command on Anaconda Prompt- conda install -c conda-forge opencv. It's in process.

Comment: @SGG So how did it go ? You can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832991/import-opencv-on-jupyter-notebook) and try their solution.

Comment: Hello Osuman. After that OpenCV was installed and I could import it on command prompt but not on jupyter notebook. Later I opened Anaconda prompt, and typed- pip install opencv and it worked. But it's in my root environment. I hope that won't create any problem.

Comment: Being in the root environment won't really cause problems, but it might be better to create an environment, activate it and install all your packages there. After that try to run jupyter notebook from that same environment and see if it works. Also please mark as answer if it helped