# How to import openCV on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, python-import

The problem: When I command `import cv2` on Jupyter notebook I get a ModuleNotFoundError: "No module named 'cv2'".

What I have tried: On Anaconda I wrote `py -m pip install opencv-python` and also `conda install opencv` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832991/import-opencv-on-jupyter-notebook?newreg=7f49873cc5c244fb89dc6b9c04d59d15) question. I also tried the command `pip install opencv-python` as explained in step 2 in [this](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) manual. But every time I got the same error (on Jupyter notebook).

I would like for help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel

I've run into similar issues and this article helped me out. You can try installing it from within the Jupyter Notbeook Kernel.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install opencv-python
```

[Article](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) I reference

Answer (score 1):

try `pip3 install opencv-python`

also try `pip3 install opencv-python==` to see all the available versions